# how to wrap text inside a div leaving other tags?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

```
<p><img src="" /> some text</p>
```

How to wrap the **text only** with `<span>` tag.

The final result should be

```
<p><img src="" /><span>some text</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing it depending on whether you're using a framework or not. Here is essentially how you could do it with vanilla js, plain old js.

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var text = ps[0].innerText;

ps[0].innerHTML = ps[0].innerHTML.replace(text, '<span>' + text + '</span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I found using text function is also useful

```
$(function(){
    $('p').text(function(i, oldText){
        return oldText;
    }).wrap("<span>");
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QA2e8/)

Answer (score 0):

If the selector matches a unique image, this will do it:

```
$("selector").html($("<span/>", { text: $("selector").text() });
```

If it matches multiple elements, you'll need to use `.each()` to process each of them separately; the body will be the above with `$("selector")` replaced with `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$('p').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).wrap('<span/>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RpteW/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('p').text();
var img = $('p img').attr('src');
$('p').html('').append('<img src="'+img+'" /><span>'+text+'</span>');
```